# Stuck in infinite loop in QEmu

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb

I have the following code, where I am trying to add a new interrupt (int 0x21) for 16-bit mode of x86:

```
void main()
{
char* str = "Enter the string!\n\r";
makeInterrupt21();
interrupt(0x21,0,str,0,0);
}
```

The interrupt and the makeInterrupt21 functions are written in assembly. The interrupt function simply calls the interrupt number as given by the first argument with rest of the arguments determining the valuses of ax, bx, cx and dx registers respectively.
The makeInterrupt21 function sets the entry for the jump address of interrupt 0x21.

```
.global _interrupt
_interrupt:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push si
push ds
mov ax, #0x100
mov ds, ax
mov ax, [bp + 0x4]
mov si, #intr
mov [si + 1], al
pop ds
mov ax, [bp + 0x6]
mov bx, [bp + 0x8]
mov cx, [bp + 0xa]
mov dx, [bp + 0xc]
intr: int #0x0
pop si
pop bp
ret

.global _makeInterrupt21
_makeInterrupt21:
push bp
mov bp, sp
push es
mov ax, #0x0
mov es, ax
mov bx, #0x84
mov ax, #interrupt21ServiceHandler
eseg
mov [bx], ax
eseg
mov [bx + 0x2], ds
pop es
pop bp
ret

.extern _handleInterrupt21
interrupt21ServiceHandler:
push dx
push cx
push bx
push ax
call _handleInterrupt21
ret
```

The handleInterrupt21 is the interrupt handler function for the interrupt 0x21 and is written in C:

```
void handleInterrupt21(int ax, int bx, int cx, int dx)
{
  char* line;
  line = bx;
  switch (ax)
    {
     case 0x0:
       printString(line);
       break;
     default:
       printString("Error invalid arguments!");
       break;
    }
}
```

The printString function prints the string starting at the address given by the argument given to it:

```
int printString(char* string)
{
 int i = 0;
 while (*(string + i) != '\0')
   {
    char al = *(string + i);
    char ah = 0xe;
    int ax = ah * 256 + al;
    interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
    i++;
   }
 return i;
}
```

When I run this code on QEmu, I get into an infinite loop which prints:

```
Enter the string!
Enter the string!
Enter the string!
```

When I ran this on QEmu, I got the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
```

Could anyone explain why am I stuck in a loop?

EDIT:
Also please explain the meaning of breakpoint trap and why am I getting this error. I read a related question on this but I couldn't understand the answer.

Comment: Why haven't you used `iret`? And aren't you supposed to continue with the original interrupt handler? What happens with the other `int 21` functions? And what happens after your program has ended?

Comment: Also the arguments need to be removed.

Comment: You need to show the code for `interrupt21ServiceHandler`. Also since you haven't saved the old INT 21h vector there's no way for your program to exit.

Comment: @RossRidge I did not understand why I need to save the old int 21h vector for my program to exit. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Jester I need to pass the arguments for the `handleInterrupt21` function. Why should I remove them?

Comment: When you return from `main` the C runtime library will call `INT 21h AH=4Ch` in order to exit. Since you've redirected `INT 21h` to your own code, your code will called rather than MS-DOS's code and so the program won't exit.

Comment: @WeatherVane I got my mistake about `iret` but could you please explain what else are you asking me? I am slightly new to x86 assembly

Comment: You need to remove the arguments after the call returns. Somebody has to otherwise they would stay on the stack. The C calling convention says it's the caller's responsibility.

Comment: @Jester Could you please also explain what is breakpoint trap...please see the edit

Comment: That might be a qemu bug - no matter what you do in the VM you should not be able to cause qemu to fault.

Comment: @Jester but how do I get around this in gdb

Comment: The final reason for the loop (in addition to the others listed above) is that you use a far call to invoke `main()` but it is a near function. Apparently `bcc` can't be told to make a far function, so you should just add an endless loop so it never returns.

Comment: There are some problems with taking over of `int 21h`. First there is already function `ah=0`, you should pick an unused one. Next, the handler tests function `ax==0` it should be `ah==0`. Next, all other functions of `int 21h` are refused - you must pass control to the original interrupt handler after your own servicing. Then when you exit the program you must restore the original interrupt handler, since your code won't exist. Finally, your string output is using BIOS function `int 10h ah=0eh` for terminal output, but why aren't you using the BIOS string output function `int 10h ah=13h`?